# Increasing the diversity of the site?

Tags: discussion

Re: this recent question:

[Black History ancestry](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/12643/1006)

It would be useful to have information here on getting started with African-American genealogy.  I might be able to construct a self-answered question, something along the lines of my answer to [Getting started in Irish research?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/5407/1006) but ideally I would like to see participation from people more familiar with African-American genealogy.

Let's think about ways that we can do some outreach and increase participation on the site from people who are working in geographical areas outside our own, and types of research outside our own areas of interest ('mental geography').

How can we be more inclusive?

Comment: I'm all for diversifying - connected directly to the Black History question and this one I expanded the scope of my imprisonment answer to include enslavery in the request for Challenge Topics at http://meta.genealogy.stackexchange.com/a/3213/19

Comment: @polygeo, you'll see I've commented suggesting the two should not be combined.